# Using replaceString in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Here is a snippet of typoscript in my project:

```
fe_users.company = TEXT
fe_users.company.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|powermail_2594|uid294
```

I am using typo3 v4.5.
Now, the content of fe_users.company.data contains some errors which I want to remove using replaceString() or removeString().I don,t have much knowledge of typoscript at this stage and thats why I am writing this question.How would I implement the replaceString function.The examples I found on inernet were dealing with .vlaue property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below typoscript:

```
fe_users.company.stdWrap.replacement {
10 {
search = &
replace.char = 38
}
}
```

Comment: According to Official Typo3 documentation, this feature is available from v 4.6 onwards:http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html while I am using v4.5

Comment: http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2011-October/077473.html

- Please check this link. This may help you.

Comment: can you please tell me what you want to remove from the data?